# Creating a "period" variable from a date variable in Stata

Tags: date, vector, time, panel, stata

I have panel data (unbalanced) with id and date to determine the two dimensions. Ids are integer numbers from 1-449. Dates are quarters from 2004Q1 to 2012Q4. Is it possible to create a new variable t which is conditioned to the date-vector?

For example:

**2004Q1 => 1**

**2004Q2 => 2**

and so on.

For a balanced panel that is no problem, but how can i make it for an unbalanced panel?

I have tried:

```
sort company_id date 
by company_id: gen t = _n
```

which actually counts the observations. Problem is, for example, `company_id = 4` does not start in 2004Q1 but in 2005Q1, so the corresonding number should not be 1 but 5.

Comment: What have you tried? Please show us your attempts. Should the quarters map to the same number for every individual? For example, `2004Q1 --> 1`, for all `id`'s.

Comment: Question is also unclear. What is your date variable? A string variable or a numeric variable (if the latter, what storage type, what display format?)?

Comment: @Roberto Ferrer: Exactly, the number should map to every indiviual.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Consider adding to the question your programming problem. This implies posting what you've tried and why it's not working for you.

Comment: @Nick Cox: Numeric variable, float and %tq.

Comment: @Roberto Ferrer:
sort company_id date
by company_id: gen t = _n

which actually counts the observations. Problem is, for example, company_id = 4 does not start in 2004Q1 but in 2005Q1, so the corresonding number should not be 1 but 5.

Answer (score 1):

One way is the following. If there are gaps in the `year`variable, they will not be considered. For example, `2004Q1 -- > 1` and `2004Q3 --> 2`, if `2004Q2` is not in the database.

```
clear all
set more off

*----- example data -----

input ///
id quarter
1 8
1 9
1 10
2 9
2 10
2 13 // note a two-quarter gap
2 14
end

format quarter %tq

list, sepby(id)

*----- what you want -----

bysort quarter: gen coun = (_n == 1)
gen qmap = sum(coun)

drop coun
sort id quarter
list, sepby(id)
```

If you want to consider gaps, then you could do something like:

```
clear all
set more off

*----- example data -----

input ///
id quarter
1 8
1 9
1 10
2 9
2 10
2 13
2 14
end

format quarter %tq

tempfile orig
save "`orig'"

list, sepby(id)

*----- what you want -----

duplicates drop quarter, force
drop id

* comment next two lines if you don't want to map years not found in the database
tsset quarter
tsfill

sort quarter
gen qmap = _n

merge 1:m quarter using "`orig'", assert(match master) keep(match)

order id quarter qmap
sort id quarter
list, sepby(id)
```

If you comment a couple of lines in this code then it will give the same results as the first block.

Another strategy that will take gaps into consideration:

```
<snip>

*----- what you want -----

summarize quarter
gen qmap = quarter - r(min) + 1

<snip>
```

Because dates in Stata are just integers, your question is really just about shifting the original dates. Shift by the "minimum" date and add 1.

Comment: Thank you for the code, the second one should the what I want (considering gaps). What do you mean by "comment a couple of lines in [the] code"?

Comment: The comment is also within the code. If you comment out `tsset` and `tsfill`, you will get the same results as in the first solution.

Comment: I wonder why you need this variable. Dates in Stata are just integers, so if you change the display format of your date variable (e.g. %9.0g) you have something like you asked for, but shifted by some constant.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the shift; in this case I can subtract the shift and get the date-vector? It´s just to see how "unbalanced" the panel is. thank you very much :)

Comment: My answer includes the "shift" strategy. It is at the end.

Comment: thank you very much, I think that´s the easiest and most efficient way to get result I wanted.

Comment: To *see* how unbalanced the data are, `scatter company_id date`, or vice versa. Also, `dotplot date`.

Comment: Dear Nick Cox, in scatter company_id date I do not see anything special, but dotplot is a very good suggestion! thank you